# Trigger automation or notification by counting other notifications

Tags: ios, automator, notifications

I have one of those rust removal systems that draws from a tank of solution when my sprinkler runs.

By counting the number of times that my sprinkler system has notified me it ran, I can know when it’s time to add more rust removing solution.

Is there a way to trigger a notification or automation after a certain number of other notifications were received?

Answer (score 2):

macOS stores notifications in a SQLite database. You can query this database for notifications that match the texts coming from your sprinkler system.

Let's say the notification from your sprinkler contains the phrase "Sprinkler turned on"

[image: sample notification]

You could set up a script to query the db for that string, and return the count of messages in the database that contain that text. And, when the count exceeds your set threshold, run a second alert script, etc.

Here's a basic zsh example (code also on my [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/luckman212/b70649f1c4b007ce0c978b06ff9742c8)). Save this as e.g. `sprinkler.sh` and make it run every 5 minutes with a LaunchAgent. Use [LaunchControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02qZV.png) if you don't know how to create your own LaunchAgent from scratch.

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

#number of times after which a refill is required
REFILL_AFTER=25

#text (case sensitive regex) that should cause the counter to increment
TRIGGER_STR='Sprinkler turned on'

#script to run when alert fires (send email, SMS, etc...)
ALERT_SCRIPT=/path/to/your/script

#directory to store data
DATA_DIR=$HOME/.sprinkler

######## DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS POINT ########

mkdir -p $DATA_DIR
touch $DATA_DIR/cnt $DATA_DIR/seen
read -r LAST_COUNT <$DATA_DIR/cnt
[[ -n LAST_COUNT ]] || LAST_COUNT=0

DARWIN_USER_DIR=$(/usr/bin/getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR)
cd "${DARWIN_USER_DIR}com.apple.notificationcenter/db2" 2>/dev/null || exit 1
[[ -e db ]] || exit 1
sqlite3 db "PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)" &>/dev/null

sqlite3 db "SELECT hex(uuid), hex(data) FROM record" >$DATA_DIR/msgs
while IFS='|' read UUID MSG _ ; do
    if grep -q $UUID $DATA_DIR/seen; then
        continue
    fi
    echo "$UUID" >>$DATA_DIR/seen
    echo "parsing new message: $UUID"
    #messages are stored in binary plist format
    DECODED=$(
        xxd -r -p <<<"$MSG" |
        plutil -convert xml1 -o - -- - |
        xmllint --xpath "//key[.='body']/following-sibling::string[1]/text()" -
    )
    if [[ $DECODED =~ $TRIGGER_STR ]]; then
        (( LAST_COUNT++ ))
        echo "matched! count is now: $LAST_COUNT/$REFILL_AFTER"
        echo $LAST_COUNT >$DATA_DIR/cnt
    fi
done <$DATA_DIR/msgs

if (( LAST_COUNT >= REFILL_AFTER )); then
    rm $DATA_DIR/cnt
    echo "time to refill the tank!!!"
    $ALERT_SCRIPT
fi
```

You can either wait for the notifications to arrive, or pre-test it with `terminal-notifier` if you have that on your system:

```bash
terminal-notifier -title 'Sprinkler system' -message "Sprinkler turned on $(date)"
```

Adjust the variables at the top of the script to control how many cycles you get per tank (`REFILL_AFTER`), the text to look for (`TRIGGER_STR`), where the temp data gets stored (`DATA_DIR`), and the path of the script to run when the alert fires (`ALERT_SCRIPT`).

**edit:** after posting this, I realized you might have been looking for a purely iOS solution. The above would require a Mac with iCloud messages sync enabled.

Comment: Yes an iOS solution would be good. But I can work with a mac solution. Right now however, the notifications that the sprinkler has run comes from the sprinkler's iOS app.  Does Mac with iCloud messages sync enabled transmit notifications received on my iPhone (from any app) to the mac?

Comment: @emiller No, only iMessage/SMS messages sync between devices as far as I am aware. Does your sprinkler system have any other facility for notifications or remote querying? Many industrial products use things like MQTT, ModBus, SNMP etc.

Comment: I did find this: https://github.com/allenporter/pyrainbird/tree/main I guess I can use this python API in some form

Comment: That Python module looks very promising, and is well maintained. I'd suggest opening a new question if you need help stringing that up.